# Transformar um array de string (que são links) em uma imagemView no android com json

Tags: java, android, json

tenho um json em um servidor com links de imagens e preciso converter para imagemView, só consegui abrir na tela do android como string monstrando o link da imagem.

meu json [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

meu codigo que recebe a json

```
 StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String string) {
            parseJsonData(string);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    rQueue.add(request);
}

void parseJsonData(String jsonString) {
    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray fruitsArray = object.getJSONArray("fruits");
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0; i < fruitsArray.length(); ++i) {
            al.add(fruitsArray.getString(i));
        }

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
        fruitsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: no lado do servidor, converta as imagens para string base64. Quando receber no android passa de base64 para imagem novamente

Comment: @AndersonCanteiro como converter o Array? ainda nao tinha pensado no base64 irei tentar, mas nao to sabendo pegar o Array que vai vim e jogar para imagem.

Comment: você vai precisar fazer seu próprio adapter, olha esse tutorial http://blog.alura.com.br/personalizando-uma-listview-no-android/, a parte que é passado o drawable do java, você faz uma função que pegue o base64 do json e transforma em imagem

Comment: @AndersonCanteiro nesse caso vou receber em string nao é? se for isso eu ja estou recebendo em string as url das imagens, e tranformei uma imagem usando base64 ficou um código muito grande, tem um exemplo?

Comment: estou recebendo o link de cada imagem no android em  array de string, só nao estou  sabendo pegar o string do array e executar

Comment: o base64 fica grande, mas depois no android você so tem que converter, no caso de você mandar a url, vc vai ter que fazer outro request para a internet. Pode ser assim também, mas o jeito que falei você faria um request só

Comment: @AndersonCanteiro vc tem um exemplo? porque sou iniciante, sobre json e esse assunto sou novo, ficaria grato, obrigado

Comment: Não precisa converter para base64. Bibliotecas como [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/) e [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) conseguem carregar as imagens das urls diretamente em um `ImageView`.

Comment: Marlos vou ver se consigo montar algo, realmente não precisa converter, falei para converter para fazer apenas um request. Mas se isso não for problema pode usar a sugestão do Leonardo.

Answer (score 0):

obrigado Anderson e Leonardo consegui resolver, achei um site com o conteudo que eu estava procurando irei deixar o link para estudo

https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/recyclerview-volley-picasso/part-1